# Reducing code with a for loop to one line in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, lambda, list-comprehension

```
n=20
a=""
for i in range(1,n+1):
    a+=str(i)+" "
    print (a)
```

I don't know about `lambda` expression.Please Help me?

Comment: Why do you want to convert this to a lambda expression?

Comment: Do you mean list comprehension?

Comment: For Codegolf exchange or learning about lambda expression.

Comment: Yes  @COLDSPEED.

Comment: Why would you want to pack 5 lines of code into an anonymous function (i.e. a lambda)? The only lesson to be learned here is "That's not how you use lambdas".

Comment: I want to minimize length of my code @Rawing.

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey Rather than minimizing its length, you should maximize its readability.

Comment: I have to submit the code in codegolf exchange @Rawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
[print(*range(1, i+1)) for i in range(1, 20)] and None
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a `lambda`, you'll need one which returns a *string*. This means you'll need a generator comprehension to generate your string.

Consequently, you'll need 2 levels of `str.join`:

```
In [856]: f = lambda x: '\n'.join(' '.join(map(str, range(1, i))) for i in range(1, x + 1))

In [857]: print(f(20))

1
1 2
1 2 3
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

It looks complicated but it is the same as a loop, condensed into a generator comprehension. We generate each line using `' '.join(map(str, range(1, i)))` for each `i` and then all such lines are joined by the newline `\n`.